# How to specify AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key as part of a amazon s3n URL

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am passing input and output folders as parameters to mapreduce word count program from webpage.

Getting below error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret
>   Access Key must be specified as the username or password
>   (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId
>   or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

Answer (score 40):

The documentation has the format: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3

```
 s3n://ID:SECRET@BUCKET/Path
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if it happens that the secret has a "/" in it. Which is quite frequent. It's an old known bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3733, and may be fixed in hadoop 2.8 for s3a protocol. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11573. The alternative is to put the keys in conf (but this has other caveats too)

Comment: It worked for emr-4.3.0. Emr-4.4.0 and emr-4,5,0 throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bucket name must not be formatted as an IP Address`, as if the ID and the SECRET were part of the bucket name. Emr-4.6.0 throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bucket name should be between 3 and 63 characters long`. Any ideas?

Comment: s3n is not supported anymore

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you use this:

```
hadoop distcp \
-Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<your_access_id> \ 
-Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<your_access_key> \
s3n://origin hdfs://destinations
```

It also works as a workaround for the occurrence of slashes in the key.
The parameters with the id and access key must be supplied exactly in this order: after *disctcp* and before *origin*

Comment: s3n is not supported anymore

Answer (score 8):

Passing in the AWS Credentials as part of the Amazon s3n url is not normally recommended, security wise.  Especially if that code is pushed to a repository holding service (like github). Ideally set your credentials in the conf/core-site.xml as:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>XXXXXX</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>XXXXXX</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

or reinstall awscli on your machine.

```
pip install awscli
```

Comment: Where to add the `<configuration>` data? My pom.xml doen't seem to like it. I'm running a Spark job on a CentOS VM, and installing and configuring AWS CLI also didn't help.

Comment: add it in this file:  `conf/core-site.xml`

Comment: What and where is this `conf/core-site.xml`?

Comment: what if there are different s3 accounts requiring different keys?

Comment: @prometheus2305 Unfortunately I was not able to solve that problem.

Answer (score 2):

For pyspark beginner:

### Prepare

Download jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws
, put this to spark jars folder

Then you can

### 1. Hadoop config file

`core-site.xml`

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<access-key>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret-key>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

### 2. pyspark config

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", secret_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secret_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem")
```

### Example

```
import sys
from random import random
from operator import add

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
        Usage: S3 sample
    """
    access_key = '<access-key>'
    secret_key = '<secret-key>'

    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("Demo")\
        .getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext

    # remove this block if use core-site.xml and env variable
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", access_key)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", access_key)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", secret_key)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secret_key)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem")

    # fetch from s3, returns RDD
    csv_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("s3n://<bucket-name>/path/to/file.csv")
    c = csv_rdd.count()
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~count~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print(c)

    spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

create file `core-site.xml` and put it in class path.
In the file specify

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
        <value>your aws access key id</value>
        <description>
            aws s3 key id
        </description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
        <value>your aws access key</value>
        <description>
            aws s3 key
        </description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Hadoop by default specifies two resources, loaded in-order from the classpath:

- `core-default.xml`: Read-only defaults for hadoop
- `core-site.xml`: Site-specific configuration for a given hadoop
  installation

Answer (score 0):

**Change s3 to s3n in the s3 URI**

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop distcp \
  -Dfs.s3a.access.key=<....> \
  -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=<....> \
  -Dfs.s3a.fast.upload=true \
  -update \
  s3a://path to file/ hdfs:///path/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

s3n://ID:SECRET@BUCKET/Path

special characters like / can be escaped using URLEncode.encode method
e.g

```
String ID = URLEncoder.encode("<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String SECRET= URLEncoder.encode("<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```