# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both source file listing and source paths present

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp, s3distcp

I am trying to copy files from HDFS to S3 using `distcp` by executing the following command

```
hadoop distcp -fs.s3a.access.key=AccessKey -fs.s3a.secret.key=SecrerKey \
s3n://testbdr/test2 hdfs://hostname:portnumber/tmp/test
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
17/09/05 02:59:30 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both source file listing and source paths present
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.OptionsParser.parseSourceAndTargetPaths(OptionsParser.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.OptionsParser.parse(OptionsParser.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:436)
Invalid arguments: Both source file listing and source paths present
usage: distcp OPTIONS [source_path...] <target_path>
              OPTIONS
 -append                       Reuse existing data in target files and
                               append new data to them if possible
 -async                        Should distcp execution be blocking
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Old Command

hadoop distcp *-**Dfs.s3a.access.key=AccessKey -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=SecretKey*** \
s3n://testbdr/test2 hdfs://hostname:portnumber/tmp/test

### Rectified Command

hadoop distcp ***-Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=AccessKey -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=SecretKey*** \
s3n://testbdr/test2 hdfs://hostname:portnumber/tmp/test

Answer (score 0):

To pass configuration parameters, you have to use `-D`

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.access.key=AccessKey -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=SecrerKey \
s3n://testbdr/test2 hdfs://hostname:portnumber/tmp/test
```

Comment: tried above command . now i am getting below error..  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924808/how-to-specify-aws-access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-as-part-of-a-amazon-s3n-u